# I keep getting this error "docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase."

Tags: r, docker, amazon-ec2, shiny

I keep getting this error even my repo name is lowercase, the code i´m running is this **sudo docker container run --rm  -p 3838:3838 -v /home/ubuntu/la-liga-2018-2019-stats/stats/:/srv/shiny-server/stats -v /home/ubuntu/log/shiny-server/:/var/log/shiny-server/ 

BorisRendon/shinyauth**. I´m trying to deploy a shiny app to aws using docker and i can´t pass this step.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `docker run` and not `docker container run`.